# Как вводить разные типы чисел в input() без указания типа?

Tags: python-3.x, input, ввод

необходимо создать две функции input()

```
a = input()
b = input()
```

Но в каждую переменную в зависимости от условий могут вводиться либо целые либо числа с плавающей точкой, как это реализовать?

Comment: Сделать функцию например `get_int`, в которой вызывается `input()` и оборачивается в `int` и при ошибке повторяется код. Для `float` аналогично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и одну универсальную функцию сделать, просто передавать в неё нужный тип в зависимости от условий:

```
def typed_input(prompt, dtype):
    while True:
        try:
           return dtype(input(f'{prompt}: '))
        except:
           print('Ошибка ввода!')

x = typed_input('Введите целое число', int)
y = typed_input('Введите дробное число', float)
```

Тип в питоне может быть присвоен в обычную переменную, так что вы можете выбрать и передать в функцию нужный тип в зависимости от ваших условий.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте уже на этапе обработки полученных данных конвертировать в нужный формат. А ввод пусть идёт любой.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]